# TypeScript: How to have default generics?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method:

```
  private createModal<A, B, C>(
    modalContentComponentData,
    modalContentComponent,
    modalComponent = ModalComponent): Modal {

    ...

    this.attach<C>(modalComponent, overlayRef, injector);

    return modal;
  }
```

and I call it like this:

```
return this.createModal(modalContentComponentData, modalContentComponent);
```

now I want to override the default value of the third parameter:

```
this.createModal<{}, any, TestComponent>(modalContentComponentData, modalContentComponent, TestComponent);
```

But this won't work. Typescript compiler says:

**Types have separate declarations of a private property 'modalData'.**

How can I fix this? I assumed that I have to create an interface, but interfaces don't provide private fields.

The constructors of ModalComponent and TestComponent are the same:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(MODAL_DATA) private modalData: any,
    @Inject(MODAL_CONTENT_COMPONENT) private cComponent: any
  ) {
    this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(cComponent);
  }
```

Comment: Please consider including a [mcve] as described in [ask] so that others can verify the issue.  Ideally you would either have a self-contained example that could be demonstrated in a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/); barring that, you could provide a link to the code in a web IDE where all the dependencies (e.g., angular or other code) are already set up.  Good luck!